# Little complex Databinding in windows form combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, two-way-binding

I am in trouble while working on Databinding in windows form. I have two classes, one is Project and another is Update. Now all project object is having a list of Updates and it is binded to a combobox, but when the user changes selection need to display/bind the properties of Update object to another controls. But is not updating as expected, when the user changes selection. Please help me on this..

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Rxh.png)

See my class and codes below,

```
public class Project
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;

    public Project(int id, string name)
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;

        ReadUpdates();
    }

    public List<Update> AvailableUpdates { get; set; }
    public int Id { get { return _id; } }

    public string ProjName
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    private void ReadUpdates()
    {
        AvailableUpdates = new List<Update>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            AvailableUpdates.Add(new
                Update(i, DateTime.Now.AddDays(i)));
        }
    }
}

public class Update
{
    private string _title;
    private int _uid;
    private DateTime _updatedOn;

    public Update(int id, DateTime updatedOn)
    {
        _title = $"Update:{id}";
        _uid = id;
        _updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }

    public int UId
    {
        get { return _uid; }
        set { _uid = value; }
    }

    public DateTime UpdatedOn
    {
        get { return _updatedOn; }
        set { _updatedOn = value; }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Update _currentUpdate;
    private Project _project;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _project = new Project(1, "Sample Project");

        DoBindings();
    }

    private void DoBindings()
    {
        NameBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", _project, "ProjName");
        IdBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", _project, "Id");

        UpdatesCombo.DataSource = _project.AvailableUpdates;
        UpdatesCombo.DisplayMember = "UId";

        _currentUpdate = (Update)UpdatesCombo.SelectedItem;

        UpdateTitle.DataBindings.Add("Text", _currentUpdate, "Title");
        UpdateDate.DataBindings.Add("Value", _currentUpdate, "UpdatedOn");
    }

    private void UpdatesCombo_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _currentUpdate = (Update)UpdatesCombo.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple. All you need is to bind the related controls to the same list data source as the combo box.

```
var updates = _project.AvailableUpdates;

UpdatesCombo.DataSource = updates;
UpdatesCombo.DisplayMember = "UId";

UpdateTitle.DataBindings.Add("Text", updates, "Title");
UpdateDate.DataBindings.Add("Value", updates, "UpdatedOn");
```

The data binging infrastructure creates [`CurrencyManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class per each unique list data source. The non list controls are actually bound to the [`Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.current(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which is updated by the combo box selection.

Comment: I'ld move the `Update` class (which has a not so good name as of now) inside Project (not a good name, too) as a child class.